# Orange: importing data with hash (#) in column name

Tags: orange

I want to load a data set which contains hash (#) symbol in the header. I work with bigrams and some of the columns are named "d#" or "z#"

According to [Orange docs](http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/visual-programming/loading-your-data/),
hash is used to attribute type information, so for some of the columns I will get error that I am using a wrong specifier ("Invalid attribute flag z").

Is there any workaround to tell orange that my labels are not attributed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prefix those header labels with a correct `type#` specifier, e.g. if you have a bag of bigrams data, replace `d#` and `z#` columns with `C#d#` and `C#z#`, marking them counts, continuous.

With some luck, Orange will interpret the first `C#` as continuous and the rest as attribute name.